# jQuery DatePicker - DatePicker Is Not A Function

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am always getting the error datepicker is not a function". If I view source in Firebug, I can click on all the jQuery script links and they are all valid. I can even do a search in the main .js file for the datepicker function and see it there.

So the function seems to be there, the rest of jQuery seems to be working - what could I be doing wrong?

It is an ASP.NET environment however I'm using a standard HTML control, so it's not a naming issue.

Doing my brain in. Any suggestions welcome.

**Update 2**

Prompted by a comment from Drew, the input control I want to be my date picker is in an update panel. Is there a workaround for this scenario?

**UPDATE**
Please see the following :

The Call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddate").datepicker();
});
```

The Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://alpha-js.example.co.uk/navigation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://alpha-js.example.co.uk/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://alpha-js.example.co.uk/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://alpha-js.example.co.uk/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://alpha-js.example.co.uk/jquery.tables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://alpha-js.example.co.uk/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/example.js"></script>
```

Comment: could you show us how you're trying to implement it, plz

Comment: check whether you have jquery.min.js file

Comment: DatePicker is part of jQueryUI (separate from jQuery), you included that too, right?  Or are you using another DatePicker?

Comment: did by any chance; you trigger an UpdatePanel before using the datepicker?

Comment: Yes Drew, the input field is within an asp.net Update Panel. Does this make more sense now?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely jQuery is not loaded at the time you are calling `datepicker`.  Make sure you are calling the function after loading jQuery.

Comment: You should probably also put the code in a `$(function(){})` block.

Answer (score 0):

Since yo say all scripts are valid in Firebug, then I'm guessing you forgot to add the binding in a [document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/%20document%20ready)-function.

You should do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Entire document/Dom/scripts are loaded now you can bind
  $( "#myElement" ).datepicker();
});
```

EDIT:
are you getting any script errors? Could be something else failing before document-ready.

You could use Google Chrome, press ctrl+shift+i, change to the scripts tab.
Down left is a pause icon (two vertical bars, fourth icon from the left). Make sure it says "Pause on uncaught exceptions", then reload the page.